# What can be the possible values of C in the following code?

Tags: operating-system, fork

```
main(){
    int child = fork();
    int c = 5;
    if(child == 0){
       sleep(1000);
        c += 5;
    } else{
        child = fork();
        c += 10;
        if(child)
            c += 5;
    }
}
```

**What have i tried ?**

The IF and ELSE block will be executed in parallel.
So, when control enters IF block, the child will go to sleep but parent will start execution and forks into 2 processes both of which execute C and make C = 15. Now, parent can only enter **If(child)** and will make the value of C = 20.

Now, Child process wakes up, and makes c = 10.
**So, possible values of C are 10,15,20 .**

**Is my understanding correct ?**

Comment: I've inserted a missing `{` and `}`: please roll back if I've put them in the incorrect place. Prior to that your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: It is 10, 15, and 20, and `sleep()` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: But in else block, Both parent and child after the fork, will execute  c += 10, so, will the value change and will be same for both .

Comment: Why don't you stick a few `printf`s in and test it for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Possible values of C are **10, 15, 20**. Your understanding (reasoning) is absolutely correct.

You can even verify your answer by executing this code.

output in on my laptop:

```
5
15
20
15
10
```